# Build errors when trying to install openjdk-8-jre on python:3.8-slim-buster image

Tags: java, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, debian-buster

I have a python script that need java runtime. I am trying to build a docker image that contains contains both python 3.8 and Java 8. Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre
    
WORKDIR /
    
ADD ./requirements.txt /
ADD ./main.py /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

However I get the following error when building the image

```
docker.errors.BuildError: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I have tried different python base images but I get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The package `openjdk-8-jre` is not available in Debian Buster repositories. The command :

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre
```

returns :

```
[...]
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jre
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

You have 2 options :

- install a newer version of JRE (`openjdk-11-jre`) if you can
- install OpenJDK 8 by downloading it manually : follow this guide https://linuxize.com/post/install-java-on-debian-10/

Comment: openjdk-11-jre returns the same error. I tried `apt install default-jre` as suggested in the second option and it returns error code of 1.

Comment: `openjdk-11-jre` is available in Debian Buster repositories : https://packages.debian.org/buster/openjdk-11-jre. I just tested the modified Dockerfile on my laptop and it works. Do you have additional info ?